# Get id of last updated row mysql in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I tried using SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() to get last id updated but it gives me zero. please help me

Comment: You must fetch `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from the same connection as the `INSERT`. Can you show the sequence of vb code that does the INSERT, then queries for the id? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: last_insert_id() gives you the id of last inserted row but you are asking about last updated row. There is a clash right there.

Comment: Good day sir, thank you for replying. according to this manual [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html) mysql_insert_id returns last inserted id or update. i just wanna get the last id of updated row.

Comment: @WebberDepor is there a way? or it is not possible?

Comment: are u using PHPmyadmin or do yuo have any GUI?

Comment: Im using PHPmyadmin. thank you in advance sir. im stuck on this for 48hrs.

Comment: @NoobProgrammer you are looking at mysql_insert_id() which is a different function than last_insert_id();

Comment: can you differentiate it? @WebberDepor

Comment: a little bit different but and since @gai's answer gives a clear solution to problem i did not write a new one. and dont forget the upvote the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your table a new column with `DATETIME` type. and choose `on update CURRENT timestamp` option from `attribute` section. In this way whenever an update occurs in the column your database will update this row automaticly. Then all yo need to do is writing your SQL command from your script.

```
SELECT id fROM table  ORDER BY name_of_datetime_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

will return only one column which is last updated one

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Connector/.NET, you will find that the MySqlCommand object has a LastInsertedId property. You can use retrieve that property value immediately after your `INSERT` query, and you don't have to execute another query.

If you're not doing `INSERT` operations, you won't get any `LAST_INSERTED_ID()` value.  If all you're doing is `UPDATE` querys, forget about `LAST_INSERTED_ID()`.

Comment: is there another way sir for getting the last id of updated row? or is it impossible? :(